# Pulling Data from six months prior to current date not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I'm trying to pull data submitted 6 months from the current date. Every day this report will run and I want it to choose the data automatically. I've entered this code and nothing is coming up. There isn't an error, it's almost as if nothing was entered on the date.

```
L.Open_Date = DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
```

However, if I have confirmed there was data entered in on the date 6 months ago. I changed the code to

```
L.Open_Date >= DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
```

and this code works. It brings back everything submitted 6 months prior to the current date.

Is there a way to get the 6 months ago data only to pull up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want:

```
L.Open_Date = DATEADD(month, -6, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

This gives you 6 months back *without the time component* (which `getdate()` otherwise returns). This would work if `Open_Date` is a `date` itself. If it has a time component that you want to ignore, then this would be:

```
CAST(L.Open_Date AS DATE) = DATEADD(month, -6, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Or the longer, but SARGable:

```
L.Open_Date >= DATEADD(month, -6, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
AND L.OPen_DAte >= DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(month, -6, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
```